# Why does execution in shell give different result that execution in batch script?

Tags: windows, loops, batch-file, cmd, echo

I'd like to list all .csv files in a directory and its subdirectories. It works nicely when I run this in the cmd terminal:

```
for /f %a in ('dir /b /s *.csv') do (echo %a)
```

When I put the same line of code into an (otherwise empty) text file (.cmd) and run that .cmd file, it outputs a blank line, but does not list any files.

Why does it make a difference whether I put the commands into a script or enter them directly (in one go) in the terminal?

Thinking it might be a delayed expansion issue, I also tried `for /f %a in ('dir /b /s *.csv') do (echo !a!)`, but this doesn't list the files either.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 2):

Double up the percent symbols in a batch file!

```
for /f %%a in ('dir /b /s *.csv') do (echo %%a)
```

Comment: Thanks a lot! That was it!

Comment: The for loop variable names get double-evaluated when they're run from a file, so `%%`->`%`. `for /? | findstr "%%"` gives `To use the FOR command in a batch program, specify %%variable instead`